# Eclipse: How to limit displayed errors/warnings to currently open files?

Tags: android, eclipse, warnings, message

I'm just getting started with eclipse and android development. One thing which is driving me crazy in eclipse is the problems panel with error/warning messages. It displays errors and warning from every project that I have added to eclipse. I only want to see feedback from the project (or ideally individual file) that I am currently working on).

For example, I have two android projects added to my eclipse workspace: HelloAndroid (a sample app) and SMSTest (an SMS2Toast example). Even with no files open, I see warning messages from both projects! Why is this!?! I shouldn't see any output unless I actually have a file open...or is this just the way eclipse works? Should I be using a different workspace for each project?

Thanks for any help anyone can give me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will get mostly what you want:

1. Open the *"Problems"* view (Shift-Alt-X-Q)
2. In the right hand corner there is a drop down arrow
3. Select *"Configure contents"*
4. Then pay attention to the **"Scope"** options

I also highly recommend in that same menu *"Group by"* -> Java problem type.

Comment: +1 for the Group By.  I've never looked at most of the configuration options in there.  Thanks Adam.

Comment: Thank you very much! This was exactly what I was looking for! Group By is also quite helpful.

Comment: Also if you are having trouble finding stuff Crtl-3 is very useful too.

Answer (score 0):

Right-click the unwanted projects and click "Close Project" you shouldn't get notifications from them at that point.

Other than that I'd recommend fixing most errors before moving away from them. If you're not prepared to complete various functions at any given time just put a stub in them that satisfies conditions with a quick `//TODO:` statement telling you to fix it later.

If you're talking about working on a page in general and the errors are combersome and annoying then try double-clicking on the tab for the file you're coding (above the code window) and it should become "fullscreen" hiding the other portions of eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this is the way eclipse works.  It makes sense in that if you make a change in one file, and it causes a compilation error in another file that you don't have open you would still want to know about it.

You CAN configure which situations are considered WARN, and which are IGNORE in Preferences > Java > Compiler > Errors/Warnings.

Also, if you only want warnings from one project you can CLOSE the other project, which would keep you from having to reconfigure a new workspace for each.